# How to update typescript manually in VS2015

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, nuget-package

I was [told](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4296#issuecomment-140224416) to update Typescript in VS2015 community edition from 1.5.4 to 1.6.1.0(Beta).
I have tried under Extensions and Updates without success:
[image: Extensions and Updates]

Also tried Nuget Package Manager as following:
[image]

I am not sure if that was the way but i think it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 1.6.1.0-beta

You can download it from [this link](http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/D/8/6D8381B0-03C1-4BD2-AE65-30FF0A4C62DA/TS1.6-Beta-D14OOB.23301.00/TypeScript_Full.exe)

Also you can view [this topic](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2015/09/02/announcing-typescript-1-6-beta-react-jsx-better-error-checking-and-more.aspx)

### 1.6.3.0

Today Microsoft released 1.6.3.0 version - [looks here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2015/09/16/announcing-typescript-1-6.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, God bless you

Comment: Today Microsoft released 1.6.3.0 version - [looks here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2015/09/16/announcing-typescript-1-6.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

We are in the process of shipping TypeScript 1.6. You should see a notification in the IDE in the next day or so. Look at the little flag icon next to the smiley face.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is correct. Each release of TypeScript for Visual Studio appears to be a new extension - not an upgrade to the old one.

Comment: I used this solution on VS 2017..... fortunately I had a notification for vs update with typescript 2.2. I was facing some issue with earlier version of typescript shipped with VS.But if someone finds a solution for just updating typescript to latest in VS without depending upon Microsoft to release an update, that would be great!